# Echo in for loop

Tags: php, html, loops, for-loop

This is my code:

```
<?php
$date = 2015-02-30;
$year = substr($date, 0, 4);
$month = substr($date, 5, 2);
$day = substr($date, 8, 2);
?>

<select>

<?php
for ($i=1; $i < 31; $i++) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php if($day === $i){ echo "selected"; }; ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
<?php } ?>

</select>
```

For the option, the number 4 should be selected. Why doesn't it work? Thanks

Sorry, I already had this in a select statement

EDIT: See the code edit above. Maybe because the

Comment: Looks like it does work, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Do you have wrapped this code in select tags?

Comment: It works for me. I just pasted your code and tried to run and it works fine.

Comment: Maybe you could be a bit more specific about how it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry pls see edit. I already had select statement

Comment: you running this has `http://localhost` or `file:///`? or hosted? I'm thinking more like `file:///`. Tell us, what does HTML source reveal? *Spidey sense* is tingling here too.

Comment: Can you view the page source for the portion of the HTML output affected by this code? If you're just refreshing the page to check this, it's possible that your browser may be retaining the previously selected value. Try loading the page in a new tab.

Comment: *♫Tic, toc,... tic toc...♫* - so, what's the verdict on my above comment? Or are you saying *"Ahhhh Fred, yeah, it was `file:///`, my bad"* and don't want to admit it *lol!* - The suspense is killing me ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: I'll just kindly show myself out then. *"Yeah Fred, you do that."*.

Comment: oh, a new edit: so now the plot thickens then. Yeah, I'm out and I'll pass on this one.

Comment: Sorry everyone pls look at the edit in the code above. I think it is the 'substr' not running first. How can I fix that?

Comment: @baileyJchoi Please answer the comment by Fred -ii- : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307112/echo-in-for-loop#comment71769351_42307112

Comment: @Rizier123 where?

Comment: I linked to it and it is under your question. How does your address bar looks like in your browser? `file:///` or `localhost`? What is the html source code output?

Comment: Plus, `$date = 2015-02-30;` guess what that is being interpreted as? `2015minus02minus30` it needs to be quoted `$date = "2015-02-30";` which is probably what started this whole mess from the beginning, had you shown us your full code from the get go.

Comment: @Rizier123 No idea what they're doing and if they'll even pay attention to ^^^ - I also voted to close from the opening of it too; "not working".

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your code in a **select** statement!

An option statement wont work without the **select** tag around it:

```
<html>

<body>

<select>  <!-- Start the select statement -->

<!-- Your Code -->
<?php
$num = 4;
for ($i=1; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php if($num === $i){ echo "selected"; }; ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php
}
?>
<!-- End your code -->

</select> <!-- End the select statement -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: See the guy's edit. I knew they had that `<select></select>` - (Spidey sense told me).

Comment: Got ghosted! FeelsBadMan.  You're spidey sense is spot on.

Comment: @ChadFisher I noticed the downvote here Chad, I can honestly say that that is not mine and you did not deserve it, given the OP's totally unclear question from the start and the too many edits "after the fact".

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks fam. I'll take whatever I can get, the love and the hate.  Give me dem minus points.

Comment: @ChadFisher You've a good spirit ;-) that's a "good" thing. Well, I have now left the question, hopefully for good *lol* Wishing you well with this. *Cheers* and you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

After your edit, it looks like this is your main problem:

```
$date = 2015-02-30;
```

This is not what you think it is. It should be quoted like this:

```
$date = '2015-02-30';
```

Otherwise, `$date` is a not a string, it's a math expression that evaluates to `(int) 1983`, so `substr($date, 8, 2);` will evaluate to `false`, not `30`, and then obviously your option won't be selected.